# Is there a right way to know how a little changing can affect all project?

Tags: architecture, project

The most of projects are splitted in too many folders and files, the problem is to look through the lifecycle of some "variable" in all project, for example, I have a react component and I'd like to know all files where it's stated and modified, all api calls it can trigger and all things can affect it indirectly (dependency tree). I'm  working in a large project and I'd like to know how a little changing can affect all project without loop all files. Is there a right way to do this?

Comment: unit testing and integration testings, as general answer. you cannot predict chaos, you Can only réducteur side effect by testing